# How to skip jest coverage threshold if no pattern matched

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a requirement to have different coverage thresholds for different react folders.

*e.g. `component` should have a threshold of 80%,
`container` should have a threshold of 75%,
`utils` should have a threshold of 80%
and check only for files changes*

I running the below command

```
jest ----passWithNoTests --coverage --changedSince=development
```

And code coverage threshold setting

```
"coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 90,
        "functions": 90,
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": 90
      },
      "**/components/**/*.js": {
        "lines": 90,
      },
      "**/containers/**/*.js": {
       "lines": 80,
      },
      "**/actions/*.js": {
       "lines": 75,
      },
      "**/utils/*.js": {
        "lines": 90,
      }
```

But if there is no file change in the `component` I get error

> Jest: Coverage data for **/components/**/*.js was not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @mfaith I don't remember the workaround but as far as I remember I couldn't get the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with that works for my project. I wanted to enforce a coverage threshold on the ci process while ensuring test files were created for changed component files. To do this I have this script which checks for changed files, filters out all the files that are not component files, then chains -- collectCoverageFrom with the file to the test cmd. This will enforce that any component files changed have a test and that the test should meet the coverage threshold specified in the jest config.

this code is in a .mjs file and  to run this in the CI process, I have a script in package.json which runs node 'script path' and as the 'npm run test' that is in my package.json as 'set CI=true && react-scripts test'

```js
import { exec,execSync }from 'child_process';
import util from 'node:util';

const promiseExec = util.promisify(exec);

try { 
    promiseExec('git diff origin/develop --name-only')
    .then(({stdout, stderr }) => {    
        const changedFiles = stdout
            .split('\n')
            .filter(Boolean)
            .filter((file) => file.includes('.component'));
        if (changedFiles.length) { 
            execSync( `npm run test -- --coverage --bail ${changedFiles.map((file) => `--collectCoverageFrom "${file}"`).join('')}`, { stdio: 'inherit', } );
        } else {
            execSync(`npm run test`, { stdio: 'inherit', }); 
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Error running tests:', err);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I have an update tp this approach, I no longer need the script above. I added coveragePathhIgnorePatterns to my jest config, EX: "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/","\\.scss$","\\.ts$","^(?!.*\\.component\\.*\\.tsx).*\\.tsx$"]. With this addition, as well as --changedSince, and --passWithnotests, I was able to achieve the expected outcome of only collecting coverage from .component files and allowing the jest runner to pass if no tests were found.